# How to delete a application of django on Docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I created a application for Django (name is accounts), but I want to delete it for a reason.
I've used Docker.
So in virtual environment, I just remove the account folder, and it works, but in docker mode, I get this error.

[image]

even i down container but it isn't working

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  What is the actual error?  How are you trying to delete the application?  What effects aren't you seeing that you expect?

Comment: Instead of deleting the app, why not just remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: It should not matter that you want to delete the app or not. I believe this is more on docker-compose issue (permission was not properly set) Did you add the project via volume?

Comment: @DavidMaze

i go to bar 's vscode i selected application (accounts)  and click enter delete keyboard 
and this issue occurs

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth
i deleted volume too but doesn't delete !

Comment: Can you delete via docker bash?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth
just by this command 'sudo rm -r acccounts' the folders delete! but another issue is i can't edit and after saving files in acccounts! and i want delete file in vscode

Comment: Got it. so it is because of permission issue. Your host user and docker container user does not match. You need to update the docker-composer.yml and dockerfile so that docker container thinks it is the same user updating/deleting the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i check my permission folders and file by `ls -l`
and i saw my accounts's folder  permission is this

[image]

after just type

```
sudo chmod 775 -R accounts
```

**or** you can change group name

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername accounts
```

and my issue is solved